# How likely is it that I will get some bacon?

Tags: monday-night-combat

According to [this wiki](http://mondaynightcombat.wikia.com/wiki/Bacon)

> Bacon, on rare occasion, is dropped by either Bullseye the mascot or a Jackbot when destroyed

However, "on rare occasion" is a rather loose way to put things.  What is the approximate drop rate percentage of Bacon?  If the rate is different for each enemy, which one is more likely to drop it?

Comment: Man, joining this site is worth it just for the weird titles of the questions.